# Trouble installing Cocoapods for first time

Tags: terminal, installation, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoapods using:

```
sudo install cocoapods
```

this is what i am receiving back

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

This is my second attempt to install cocoapods. The first attempt to install failed and said I may need to install ruby-dev? I tried to install that then started receiving the above message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! After using "gem" I ran into the following issue:

```
    Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200415-22388-129pjat.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out
```

I discovered that I needed to install some additional items from xcode using:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After about 20 minutes of installing and rebooting the computer i was then able to use:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

The right command for installing Cocoapods is:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

As shown on their [Getting Started](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) page.